# Performance of copying IDs from a string variable to integer List

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I am returning Model Ids separated by `;` into a string Property from a razor view using `SelectListItem` in a `ListBox`.

I would like to copy each Id from the string Property and assign each to a `List<int>` IDs, where I can use each ID to obtain more details on a Model with that ID.

I have done the following logic as preparation to solving the main issue.
However I feel that I might be compromising performance.

```
//ID returned from ListBoxFor
string receivedIDs = "1020;8922;333;14;58;446;70;98";

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
List<string> subStr = new List<string>();

int pos = receivedIDs.IndexOf(";");
int i = 0;
int prevPos = pos;

while (pos > -1)
{
    string tempStr = "";
    if(i == 0)//Start
    {
        tempStr = receivedIDs.Substring(0, pos);
    }
    else
    {
        tempStr = receivedIDs.Substring(prevPos + 1, (pos - prevPos-1));
    }

    subStr.Add(tempStr);                
    if(i > 0)
    {
        prevPos = pos;
    }
    pos = receivedIDs.IndexOf(";", pos + 1);
    i++;
    if(pos == -1)//Last Value
    {
        tempStr = receivedIDs.Substring(prevPos + 1);
        subStr.Add(tempStr);
    }        
}            
//Coverting string values to int
foreach(string str in subStr)
{
    numbers.Add(Int16.Parse(str));
}
//Now i can check each ID in my Database Table
```

Comment: `List<string> subStr = receivedIDs.Split(";").ToList()`?

Comment: You could avoid all these ugly string operation by using `receivedIDs.Split(';')`. But regarding performance there is only one way to go: measure, then decide if it is adequate or needs improvement.

Comment: `However i feel that i might be compromising performance` In most cases you should go for the code that is easiest to maintain which usually also means easiest to read. Worrying about performance is not always the correct choice. In this case it seems you are showing a limited number of values on the screen, performance would likely never be a concern and to worry about it would be a micro optimization at best.

Comment: I couldn't agree with Klaus' comment more. If your delimited input string is 10 items or even 10,000 items long, it is very unlikely that you will see any _noticeable_ performance impact from simply using `Split(";").Select(Int.Parse)`. But the best way to tell is to measure it. Don't fall into the trap of over-optimizing!

Comment: How many IDs are you returning?

Comment: @trailmax I am receiving maximum of 10 IDs, but this can change to even more IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to convert `receivedIDs` from a `string` to a `List<int>`.

In that case, this is a quick way to do it:

```
string receivedIDs = "1020;8922;333;14;58;446;70;98";
List<int> numbers = receivedIDs.Split(";").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

What we're doing is:

1. Splitting your input `string` at each `;` character using `Split(";")`
2. Parsing each number into an `int` using `Select(int.Parse)`. This means that you take each token from the previous step and you execute `int.Parse` on it.
3. Turning it into a `List<int>` using `ToList()`

Note that you'll need `using System.Linq;` for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine and it saved lot of codes.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent example of a problem where optimizing too early can be a waste of time.

It's tempting to assume the question is:

> Which is faster, a simple `Split(';')` or custom, optimized parsing code?

But the better question is:

> Will different ways of writing this code make a difference in performance that is noticeable to the user?

You can often write some "clever" code to do things really fast or efficiently, but that takes extra time to write and is usually difficult to understand and debug. If it turns out that the performance difference is small, it is best to always err on the side of **simpler, readable code**, even if it's not perfectly optimal.

So how do you know when the performance difference is big enough to matter? By benchmarking!

I installed [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html) in an empty console application and tested your parsing loop against `Split(';')` for ~5000 numbers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace BenchmarkDotNetTester
{
    public class ParseDelimitedStringToListOfInts
    {
        private const string inputData = "1020;8922;333;14;58;446;70;98;1272;2193;3238;2340;7779;4708;5211;2156;4867;8614;2134;2364;9532;8810;5565;9263;5243;5579;6247;6549;452;6101;9304;4228;3329;889;9797;8069;8096;8669;516;3983;5855;8256;5462;9453;3222;5031;3672;2597;8098;9303;1748;4616;8835;4206;4430;6853;318;6723;7612;7758;1962;160;4780;8161;2563;4276;7196;6999;3265;9444;3458;8570;7385;8377;4966;7298;619;8934;4309;2675;5633;7739;7852;9655;7960;3620;2316;9097;8389;7158;4087;6128;8746;7077;2054;9657;9665;6438;8712;8403;3747;5299;8030;447;2635;9067;4282;3884;1759;6582;8404;9227;1319;1895;2222;8916;4188;5683;3266;5541;6253;4984;704;1008;7995;9040;6667;466;7641;3385;8325;3085;6995;7679;7468;6982;6745;4248;3618;5174;7489;2910;2021;8554;108;4966;1551;8383;1586;7742;7637;435;2203;9595;8410;7321;8184;3640;2473;8297;4185;1793;9196;7372;2051;9848;4462;4211;9654;8597;1129;2047;5312;8076;1021;6237;7413;5051;500;1397;352;5088;6880;2205;8834;6906;7607;3614;7250;5626;9049;5473;7835;4408;6475;472;1991;9707;4846;7447;8189;6681;2555;2654;2469;1789;9066;3869;5321;2217;1976;7983;2022;337;5333;8040;8774;1483;6037;6324;1188;981;1426;9681;554;9900;2059;9445;9104;7504;8113;1569;3164;8511;7645;9724;6995;4056;5451;8606;7072;9433;5765;9770;5086;3190;8812;6819;3683;588;8496;7196;3060;200;473;5591;2484;4216;5155;9834;3635;4586;3110;9264;9387;5749;7935;5677;6453;9275;169;1717;8281;7150;5606;3444;7779;8425;1255;445;1828;9862;4986;7593;5272;289;8480;2932;794;5583;3810;6849;7818;6706;3063;5885;1662;152;2009;1123;1891;4192;4188;8773;4543;6440;9515;3055;4722;7623;9722;831;7574;4771;872;1939;4794;7347;7380;6000;6344;5688;6178;7003;8437;2805;8002;2560;809;5464;6314;9340;2845;8036;3943;281;6783;9496;6207;8269;165;633;6665;6157;752;3621;9300;760;6314;7211;8672;311;1979;7119;9536;1377;5399;2514;965;9055;6918;890;8052;168;2626;6772;2373;7055;5824;7016;5073;2399;8003;7865;8004;7512;270;3131;5670;9743;6718;6899;4547;7271;8344;660;8648;7221;6439;1896;5481;4242;1934;624;5299;9750;782;2964;5189;5869;4896;4123;4114;1589;8232;6346;3542;1346;1036;5472;1784;1343;9941;3217;7458;6554;6032;7788;9582;72;1134;1784;558;7578;9148;2003;7203;8875;912;3134;4492;429;8793;1402;3559;5826;1218;9035;6721;1938;9956;7846;5136;4311;3516;890;7026;67;9858;8800;5389;3398;5724;2845;3786;8036;9118;5595;4729;6773;8211;210;6927;1197;3588;6983;8429;2496;2020;9764;8350;6685;6359;9321;1922;3462;3181;625;551;3943;6797;3634;9033;6895;3626;1944;4366;4097;9617;7502;663;8358;5066;8291;6859;7193;4100;4178;8015;310;7273;6712;6026;6984;3198;8804;7766;3246;6143;382;1662;6758;6061;3514;8933;1875;3458;6306;4306;4037;7947;9529;4107;6385;8908;9991;2726;9768;2314;3727;1379;2639;4533;4779;4659;8102;1097;2688;980;2508;6236;8312;1772;8112;2136;862;3608;7320;4545;2770;34;2864;2337;8051;9170;6378;2232;2273;2425;868;3646;1869;4875;6663;8198;7723;9034;8447;4835;986;7252;9382;1561;6395;7302;9662;7047;7612;8833;6429;7336;5803;8584;5224;8757;3495;9823;6774;826;9051;9894;8819;6088;7414;7688;689;8184;2428;5346;367;9645;5505;5287;1970;3877;4426;7843;2137;8238;9902;4941;2579;9188;1350;8195;3458;3514;4437;39;576;526;4570;9953;466;4723;109;1747;2013;8036;8209;3349;7861;6708;6927;7034;1015;9259;1792;1638;9868;2587;2672;4627;1367;370;5586;2669;4539;6604;6653;8031;2805;3666;3859;7537;7073;1643;8514;9392;9616;6584;4516;8323;7023;5904;7709;3193;4893;7423;9172;2520;4128;9396;6481;6725;9759;6801;4506;7872;1361;5734;9501;7104;8276;2467;9913;7774;9677;1884;328;7592;8932;6414;7142;5980;5412;3910;1171;994;3121;5347;5271;5684;1124;4921;160;7875;8234;1137;2397;7593;2297;200;9808;4124;8899;2132;8131;2108;166;7306;4660;2612;8381;5468;8758;7352;4191;8846;3307;6011;6226;5354;4776;3187;1924;1863;3050;2599;742;8760;1170;543;6362;1628;4899;6767;3074;1842;9698;7416;2164;6008;3784;6092;3707;3592;368;3579;6444;6173;40;8030;8908;6620;491;5789;2501;3509;5512;5830;8874;7278;9146;4784;4189;9955;3957;8798;6121;4543;6867;2160;9874;104;9195;8681;211;5066;1610;607;8089;4960;745;4262;675;5244;4712;8250;9595;4846;867;9909;1950;9081;1697;2080;4005;2145;2119;2254;484;6058;7805;2487;3713;2187;8866;7510;9586;3919;651;5740;6050;308;6970;2649;2085;8486;9347;9567;9370;3457;452;6368;8941;2318;5544;5476;625;2336;7202;8643;2318;4754;5488;2807;5307;8956;1606;4358;3947;5057;1231;665;7142;1031;1378;6954;9026;8481;8081;5815;4186;7015;7556;6923;3679;5279;3978;6844;712;1622;4151;4446;5227;6802;2898;5785;4161;9444;6436;8102;6157;7113;4206;9526;250;9271;7664;3835;5066;2004;968;1523;9413;4951;3797;9876;4613;639;4623;347;7048;5499;2756;6934;4217;7328;7894;8304;2543;8393;4066;100;6642;500;5477;4200;258;7414;5900;2595;9960;533;9929;502;1615;2789;6654;5180;6541;4761;8560;236;7603;3054;3871;9274;1883;8184;7249;1320;8019;4914;232;1716;1001;6918;9356;1588;6275;7855;5932;6919;610;8215;4506;6114;9006;1879;516;96;4770;3282;4901;1426;3534;2370;5253;2763;2343;15;1533;8890;1362;5017;5758;734;4973;7580;3968;4620;2415;3612;1654;6550;6810;2222;1857;7347;3205;8353;4619;725;478;1457;7053;6408;8053;1919;6598;2657;7609;6014;5791;2003;4889;712;5560;8528;5745;5691;489;6851;8608;5854;1353;9734;1773;7540;9586;8676;832;1623;358;1753;7522;3521;4142;788;5987;2280;3592;276;8822;5800;145;1142;3493;48;2148;8419;6493;750;8686;6382;6839;8762;3077;1527;5419;2063;7127;9284;9780;5971;5281;1687;799;4142;5495;9560;341;6565;7176;8505;3338;4170;9243;2691;6150;6947;9987;8026;5805;4823;6763;9127;3784;2666;1190;3615;5205;2241;9507;4744;7805;7947;263;4815;8916;6829;9271;8939;2859;5515;5538;7299;6254;8010;7593;2694;6471;7538;9470;5100;3169;3362;739;9746;3325;6566;4455;832;2889;3319;770;4895;2502;2539;4975;6242;4518;5911;3839;7045;3725;5149;6321;8753;4732;1623;3364;6757;8207;5812;5026;7911;4147;7131;2321;5262;7711;6377;4026;6753;9993;4636;4355;9881;2998;3518;7773;2009;1643;8412;2931;59;8045;1534;2070;8197;2857;9476;8640;8365;6309;4882;3388;5131;2155;627;2710;4113;7931;7642;9532;2256;5939;3539;2446;63;2459;9324;7849;2657;7383;1210;9339;6422;9649;2813;3017;1850;1609;4224;8867;8029;899;5581;4243;5914;135;1757;6712;8883;4132;5666;9429;5012;6076;6710;6373;8854;6426;5079;7791;4654;3671;7485;9988;6428;3484;6159;673;1273;74;7308;6056;709;8170;6844;7177;4437;632;166;952;7573;9078;5143;7326;429;4902;9425;5733;6504;9747;3456;2773;8087;9314;7185;6599;6866;1207;3867;3894;179;6413;1096;5163;6050;5613;1007;2926;767;8707;5007;9387;9836;1581;5630;657;4475;967;6831;6964;9347;3137;7620;9709;371;6704;804;575;7950;6906;1371;5458;8744;9343;7854;1570;9139;6985;1452;8333;8407;8526;8579;3689;2978;5401;7391;567;4285;6763;3800;1348;7053;2195;1943;5972;7321;5237;7847;1863;5152;7139;6622;9804;9732;2238;4144;6057;6267;6650;9365;7019;4250;8343;4142;704;5709;8171;2308;3867;5991;8788;2291;8991;3907;9604;2726;6870;4164;2114;3116;3708;9758;8640;4346;1852;4746;9736;6374;8074;9146;4317;16;4857;3748;4943;4137;8762;8170;3428;5225;9371;9705;4767;4996;1988;3712;1513;9123;1611;7906;5388;5301;1509;7556;2274;1218;4974;8232;9710;6154;4840;4609;4004;5203;4930;8118;3726;8965;9913;1181;3707;2606;238;8;5924;742;6468;9012;8329;7357;9509;1509;3784;3619;6328;2764;9616;8480;6919;3434;1194;5379;4523;3221;8757;5238;9629;801;6493;1081;1915;2440;6521;2168;8330;1280;5621;3908;318;8838;8132;141;200;6398;6287;1962;7962;4080;1480;3818;1149;7158;9989;9557;4675;8634;4655;2271;6431;4068;5189;2919;5467;5593;2195;3319;6532;3801;8363;4035;6645;4631;1932;6292;9659;6392;5773;7150;8765;9585;3944;915;4615;2925;2885;2899;3296;1865;2102;6759;2581;3616;9013;7880;968;8328;614;1021;938;3574;7024;7086;3532;9475;9833;241;4286;9321;1145;5179;3211;3383;9667;7561;2932;9998;6062;9540;8369;2638;11;2169;5216;1735;4562;2122;8172;8024;8655;6627;7204;8223;1062;8726;810;9265;3866;9402;6145;5211;9161;7503;1284;5117;2530;444;6091;8340;7701;4051;252;4671;9694;8248;460;3600;4613;2962;2916;6532;910;271;4912;2680;2721;8773;6819;9001;6431;5462;6611;6656;9340;512;564;1621;6839;5052;8080;8859;1241;6290;3187;662;1046;7065;7268;8498;7020;1001;7880;7834;680;5289;2186;9993;3500;8713;2300;4826;8377;9806;1389;1222;4380;3037;4641;975;7920;1230;5011;547;854;1855;7928;546;7155;2440;3271;2002;3865;2924;3907;7881;9719;1272;2342;2056;5627;554;1523;612;1823;1442;1392;3168;2223;715;8771;1081;2312;8685;4015;4714;4877;9728;8940;5934;6884;9024;1816;6397;7376;4221;1380;2296;2875;3822;3201;1886;2122;3239;5244;5244;4866;9366;6300;1410;8985;8783;7524;1945;6054;6377;3649;5691;5092;6532;151;8734;7095;178;6945;5468;2594;7016;1160;1373;6935;5182;767;4902;7865;5479;6561;9600;5119;5157;6776;3788;1440;5221;3243;6089;8545;8880;8846;9432;3381;464;8239;2403;7373;1009;7521;3038;3298;2659;682;7674;4778;1887;4119;4277;706;5189;5767;9153;2290;3751;328;4241;136;6153;2630;1858;8058;9677;6162;5283;3671;3353;8931;4159;324;490;8644;2888;1323;6136;6760;5400;3588;2939;1114;388;3499;8995;7152;9685;2077;1660;7144;238;1601;8916;5415;5698;2992;9513;7413;1683;4430;9347;8746;7536;8635;2476;4001;7229;3741;3068;3600;5095;4601;478;4339;2130;161;4970;1604;9009;8810;3317;2659;3113;4607;3319;5659;2017;8498;5047;9382;7914;4434;1024;1235;2506;5984;1910;4769;649;9341;8135;6762;7486;8921;1300;6007;5581;8356;9360;194;8282;9427;1634;7517;7536;1544;1014;6176;3133;9859;8259;1323;9074;6788;3657;9607;996;3457;2620;3461;2671;5412;2335;5383;7269;7516;3420;223;4342;8960;8161;7531;5147;6003;6583;9325;1705;8473;5014;6833;157;3120;6556;2563;7678;4547;7222;4293;1331;6790;2074;6717;6565;707;5097;4535;3476;5143;2099;8109;1501;5737;9824;8494;6473;1527;6443;65;7035;3261;6648;1092;9281;315;2488;6944;1268;9482;9458;9021;5939;4653;27;2951;3307;8909;7345;5172;8195;4688;9805;9463;9945;836;4043;2167;9334;1481;2183;4332;1506;1194;1980;7136;735;4961;5711;7791;5369;2823;9239;5743;4931;6884;8433;6514;3790;9005;2466;1816;2853;3884;9987;890;1083;997;6414;4509;4355;2106;7569;4733;4024;2839;7962;4199;5289;9921;9148;1791;9072;9306;6059;9699;8843;127;5127;8836;729;9578;5835;6027;4420;904;3866;9941;6251;3919;1166;5607;1100;463;4940;2971;2691;5528;6600;7105;2139;8730;2034;5734;5124;6142;5159;3033;812;1055;3594;6176;5028;2137;7703;1291;3449;6884;9115;6147;9323;8738;3959;9993;8486;4961;5656;9980;3733;6498;2315;5206;1182;8466;2806;7626;6856;8499;2005;6482;8191;278;1674;8314;6500;9917;330;6897;4540;3484;7896;4806;5282;4631;4897;7252;4061;9004;5359;864;571;4332;380;1173;8450;8689;7013;3885;2618;3958;3381;3286;7546;743;8446;1373;524;78;3801;6598;9926;5519;7715;7059;3978;4674;9998;1670;7997;6211;862;5010;3388;8714;1748;2673;8558;9895;4600;5805;9682;7144;7017;2810;1215;9702;659;3622;1705;1748;9897;7353;8412;2192;3186;6503;5841;7345;2954;3078;7290;7717;2835;6906;8929;9831;932;1092;8317;9545;4605;3382;5417;1701;895;3845;4378;7818;3468;7741;9578;8701;3696;4539;6325;5816;8011;4510;6796;3581;8707;1353;1702;988;6264;1370;1913;8396;7268;1141;3842;644;9834;6829;3363;8240;8175;6186;887;2003;8590;6963;9789;7548;3814;911;849;5068;9860;3599;7120;7873;9452;6536;276;9525;1952;905;386;8168;1038;6725;6351;2197;1025;6827;3301;5376;806;1209;1686;421;3880;8772;1528;9411;6769;449;1879;1653;9801;4308;5530;6698;9019;9433;7789;2558;6035;6714;7211;8262;7838;7966;9250;3962;8189;4524;3894;8201;626;843;6368;4297;2631;3761;8745;5400;8795;78;7842;9661;812;9460;2036;1811;5097;5682;728;6264;682;5994;6578;3096;5489;2964;7687;3947;6396;6862;2642;9950;1585;4436;7633;9022;6458;753;3339;1861;6690;8228;3281;3956;7727;8577;1238;5384;8908;2604;4326;6195;8268;3572;5895;4415;307;1915;624;3568;5865;4982;3090;4593;8497;3990;2776;4017;7198;1762;7540;2170;2954;8917;517;1136;8414;4157;1244;8496;2974;5851;1661;9629;9741;7927;5487;551;1719;1004;3466;5829;4281;4501;9416;2831;5538;5199;2689;3478;6736;6989;7385;8945;9135;629;6859;7996;2080;3531;26;5674;7951;7664;8279;1339;827;1102;267;6830;8908;5213;7046;829;957;7797;1932;3667;3730;6257;1523;3361;4363;2529;1179;103;9335;6451;2186;1188;5590;4939;5932;9976;1897;3730;6122;9082;4467;3364;5527;3104;4520;8038;1129;4697;2831;9723;8854;8639;6033;9856;409;7553;2505;1723;5824;624;8982;142;872;11;2249;1872;1495;1988;6166;941;8281;5964;8616;4477;1402;3018;5607;4562;6630;9877;610;3900;1537;4965;8213;2020;8771;7989;1538;2196;7009;521;5202;6979;2581;5340;7596;1154;4939;1822;8586;6707;1854;8769;1873;9264;180;6852;4463;3661;4222;9316;7265;3006;6280;1063;8347;5019;5729;9783;8330;2590;6083;5578;3291;1866;8522;6608;9975;3338;5577;7930;858;1206;851;8889;712;6767;9712;4692;7788;8113;1590;9541;7417;1798;2195;2231;8149;9028;3489;936;7452;5272;6898;2667;6724;4462;101;4705;5806;7099;2316;4497;8312;1181;7607;5580;4474;611;1593;1412;8745;2388;236;1999;9549;1021;5321;1198;8529;4774;8034;2672;1745;8324;2612;8870;6991;3199;7607;3610;4580;2149;8019;2673;9329;947;2465;8822;6349;8849;8731;4809;714;2228;3981;9339;835;6301;9036;4204;732;4546;1589;8139;1005;9485;2653;254;6858;529;1791;7594;2648;1348;2715;5933;7925;5930;9037;3201;3261;1144;8000;9768;3494;8693;6048;1311;8253;9212;436;2311;624;8207;5904;8421;1875;316;3202;2635;5787;2739;3382;8916;4597;3143;9508;9955;6146;2185;2433;6689;5113;4885;7290;3033;1708;8236;5998;4074;6584;7865;7338;6483;605;6579;5778;6656;438;5530;1809;5533;988;4169;8416;8220;2473;3732;1370;9344;2536;9830;3134;5371;458;5984;7168;8479;6807;4442;9818;9078;426;3336;4486;7706;1310;81;4381;7365;1309;9859;9813;4980;7380;7784;6708;1886;169;8510;3085;2873;6880;761;3824;3725;1571;512;1857;462;8181;6806;9696;6874;7071;6099;3799;4483;9406;7974;4592;7216;6440;6340;5780;993;6665;7866;5966;2516;7290;8584;7154;4013;2957;5751;6127;6194;7836;3732;2818;5915;5626;4755;2609;7262;5777;5775;697;5510;299;9750;1861;172;8936;5748;1310;5176;8276;9469;878;3508;352;3470;3308;1921;2460;766;826;8814;6348;4264;5780;2017;8828;3889;8705;8387;5942;9743;1346;9;1610;8094;6813;9582;9939;48;4596;9876;9060;2328;7770;5170;945;1306;6639;630;9782;134;1944;1851;8217;5575;1683;8682;9702;8204;455;9244;580;4654;7395;9807;6898;8943;5530;3490;4616;1347;8686;3656;7151;3969;831;8167;2269;1433;6844;7623;4899;8151;6424;3140;7006;7199;8638;2138;4332;1339;4563;110;9243;7478;7244;1983;7527;4445;5970;5675;5138;9713;9093;4677;4318;7383;9131;6812;1291;3253;5683;465;3084;5520;4695;5910;7109;6382;9508;9045;1444;3784;949;2872;3388;8461;8790;9198;5090;7853;2690;2101;6111;2955;9071;3292;3446;2829;1744;3422;249;7963;1548;6773;2937;2461;1850;7548;3853;6868;5388;7649;922;4712;6651;5101;8858;7306;6530;3410;4343;1309;8115;3968;5519;4081;3978;5104;652;271;8706;9434;8823;4753;5455;3548;5659;2395;8543;9911;4164;7403;2906;8380;7820;6940;6430;6828;4210;8482;2109;8274;8953;2521;1049;399;3509;9581;5930;8828;4546;8626;8882;1115;2409;2599;1441;8536;2299;2498;1118;3134;6015;9554;465;4761;5095;9274;3391;8022;6232;3095;7676;6670;1488;8505;8921;2364;667;8127;1049;9875;8255;4745;1700;8353;3009;3899;2910;6366;6658;9976;195;3522;2341;5521;7596;4692;2837;5132;2241;185;5435;4484;5068;1624;3667;3943;5905;9723;4562;6850;684;7990;6736;7036;9319;5483;6893;4773;5885;2593;5449;4695;3826;4208;867;4408;2064;8689;6247;4723;2211;9196;1127;6431;6577;9795;2690;7299;2814;6469;5993;203;6590;8003;5773;6795;8781;2682;2987;9799;5804;1834;9155;1442;7440;473;6717;5216;4024;5900;2426;5694;4285;555;2026;6634;5872;9053;9289;4619;4343;4982;2651;5075;5727;7862;429;2384;8335;972;5129;8335;8890;4193;1448;4269;1183;3260;4193;7376;7324;5254;1737;3645;21;2301;7927;9795;7408;6421;7366;534;6554;6919;7859;6530;6470;1010;472;4409;316;6599;578;821;1845;1727;4048;4680;7235;5460;3209;8973;6031;8282;8308;9941;125;9966;8893;9975;1216;9301;2678;8967;4174;7226;8963;1292;6038;8275;7734;8389;7912;8977;8726;5620;5061;3200;3691;7635;7970;3104;4949;7277;7210;5181;3464;2581;2687;5774;1303;7100;5158;3081;5926;6036;3430;6367;9370;4169;8509;125;346;2368;134;4003;4428;3090;592;9913;2348;8321;3345;4460;7896;4749;3834;2148;1945;4449;4990;6166;3144;4976;6057;5032;6589;9639;751;1391;9347;9883;2615;1437;5684;4353;8858;4478;3017;8710;7802;3587;9795;9845;3633;9571;9156;8289;467;6908;3898;8549;8360;9729;6823;9780;30;1344;2844;7111;548;3196;6671;6350;2617;8801;3322;5609;4420;7651;7805;4219;4338;7669;4648;6019;5328;6320;5218;9650;6912;7954;54;4521;7549;5915;5413;904;5204;2677;897;866;9587;5588;1409;6684;3517;7442;4736;1379;3216;8862;9822;8764;9144;7823;9436;3596;3743;6867;6543;2026;1757;2898;7351;4649;1532;5748;2318;8973;183;81;9791;1762;92;4347;8265;1016;5522;1503;7756;5258;1769;7273;7347;6278;1925;756;9563;187;6278;3892;3811;1025;2975;888;6306;9611;6393;1031;2800;4282;8916;7456;7466;6379;1416;9125;5058;7172;7011;9302;1082;7634;1055;1400;5189;4394;6214;2083;3586;2497;3156;6826;4545;6535;9797;7703;7503;2846;9923;3618;4372;592;6327;1399;918;7862;1474;3314;9158;8016;1022;8178;2007;3445;2393;6657;623;1425;6138;5559;7539;3089;173;5007;237;2690;9367;1554;5697;3480;6799;2882;1074;3783;3605;3785;6889;8467;8377;5225;6899;4758;9758;7684;446;5546;6431;7260;9171;8164;3690;4518;8216;3307;4003;9771;3687;124;2998;6105;8211;5836;7804;2345;9187;8591;7509;2338;687;6500;8716;4086;3279;6694;1499;3655;1114;9095;6239;9597;2954;731;6929;1070;5081;424;7555;9894;1454;7188;2075;9054;6518;6018;1100;9743;448;9980;329;5203;1034;2546;5051;4758;3962;1414;8411;3959;7308;6132;6848;8569;3233;2470;5499;9968;2465;8551;8559;505;6942;9982;4061;1045;3782;335;8298;4237;2894;1215;5958;9789;6641;5363;6377;3436;1591;570;2691;2528;4007;5527;6581;631;1683;2763;3772;6915;2318;8087;8134;6371;2860;1709;3615;6501;2204;5477;5362;5296;2245;1329;8722;1054;7698;223;1821;5384;6480;6151;5711;2974;1778;3931;4566;1748;8927;7468;9682;4899;6673;9811;903;5891;7217;5784;6409;2968;5887;2603;52;3178;7267;5170;8561;2902;7246;9653;4098;4977;6588;574;6807;186;2192;5191;279;8920;8223;6289;8297;2943;8105;9501;1517;2496;7161;2664;5498;9891;6663;2698;6549;4112;7818;7380;2286;1849;7746;9355;2652;9352;7225;1562;7559;9674;9141;7134;2491;2667;2811;9183;8553;559;5936;2859;5143;3403;3045;9612;4048;6445;711;3010;7765;1567;4012;6944;2869;3579;3767;8190;3921;8202;9642;1846;5066;649;2868;8444;3509;30;8739;6326;148;897;5926;611;50;1033;7908;7642;14;2929;7818;6687;253;2314;5730;3618;8241;2112;3085;718;2006;7942;1342;1091;4364;4973;326;4790;44;1888;2862;6836;3326;9822;1241;391;2679;3787;6664;9228;7456;2723;9798;6116;3633;959;2484;7390;2861;2945;6097;8357;4693;4893;8007;6414;1073;9113;2853;9856;1335;3177;1786;1760;399;6144;7900;5103;3433;9151;162;1844;7754;7294;6618;2554;7308;3860;3683;5004;2147;8044;1425;4488;566;9889;2397;9048;4638;8496;982;4836;8032;2183;6377;4559;6692;4760;7602;6391;7128;4365;4699;549;8834;9559;8606;3085;1066;5601;8504;5584;2473;4903;8688;2649;8741;2421;4442;4367;3466;810;5704;5206;939;8241;7933;8933;9785;3084;9454;7094;2978;6765;4783;3871;8675;9289;3607;5850;4304;1624;2332;8777;7304;7825;9494;8945;1868;9562;2478;2015;5303;6283;2530;2627;4723;4925;5020;5162;2967;4851;4802;7257;9728;4917;8289;9255;9364;458;7225;6003;7749;1499;2962;2316;6921;4291;3488;4186;1741;9233;6949;357;4572;668;3335;5689;3560;5103;9747;828;2371;1092;9207;3148;4633;9518;2175;196;4375;963;5981;9129;407;6203;4365;636;9770;4952;344;3678;766;4297;359;8706;2082;6043;6963;2200;2098;8835;8871;7559;8849;3599;1167;1144;5661;7740;5116;8221;4402;7472;4210;2466;1236;594;3138;1680;6441;6867;7801;6395;2197;1694;2693;6050;7014;9621;7663;820;8941;5908;2571;4690;5995;101;3525;794;6030;4050;8344;7978;7845;2658;9335;5502;6213;1057;9550;7185;72;6367;2449;9824;892;6742;2892;5160;7771;2799;5372;2544;745;7517;869;4414;3765;7972;6775;1709;460;2271;9893;5899;5729;8792;2056;5420;5377;7898;4779;1801;5682;1826;9880;5498;4433;9727;6533;3514;8684;6952;6097;8884;958;2268;5086;8818;375;3510;6061;5809;6173;4576;7260;4342;356;7052;6777;9167;3634;4773;751;4078;499;360;7561;411;3636;8027;6155;2140;2194;1502;9117;8303;8364;256;9694;9684;5781;6382;2090;9162;3504;1049;1679;9047;164;4258;2315;908;7889;7666;6101;3924;4819;925;6638;3783;9190;6805;4188;8558;227;2132;3100;9394;2988;86;4446;2221;2944;6213;9628;2577;2174;6084;2944;9168;1475;8089;8979;2310;3373;4949;6860;7468;6904;615;1622;4463;6172;579;7783;548;2136;3942;2396;756;1925;3534;986;3174;3219;1793;6707;9206;8049;2769;8261;8798;2805;7171;6412;2553;4507;7907;6118;329;98;9595;4965;8323;4093;9311;5281;1152;7787;2352;9392;6934;5631;2914;5434;8318;981;8890;8722;5517;9937;3944;9663;2578;9370;5517;1984;963;6692;3078;3911;5172;3036;3372;8137;4454;2696;9959;6965;6689;1257;5523;5635;4770;1602;995;8531;4740;5306;3779;5769;7386;9077;2890;3433;171;3710;9237;9089;3546;5005;2005;9657;6842;1024;8803;3026;7994;1009;7538;1851;7732;4999;8222;1878;3909;8287;57;6351;7848;7313;8095;5218;3730;5870;83;8054;9974;1315;6900;1807;9809;9068;9403;2072;8438;7043;1282;9236;3205;3338;8122;6011;7341;9662;3054;3866;3102;311;3084;7364;8059;3903;2728;2802;8864;6850;5672;6455;3914;5783;7728;2536;7274;2836;5661;7710;2437;8497;5129;2704;7651;5120;5603;9828;2685;7407;3678;7383;2557;7109;9899;9257;1369;8292;5467;2086;6098;7137;6042;5597;2503;7274;7265;2592;2216;5415;4281;3679;6712;9311;774;3582;585;4281;8917;1853;8678;1720;4062;2758;9160;3119;5085;32;7804;6637;8418;5156;5414;3581;8776;2951;681;2609;8414;8412;9249;7445;2660;7397;9228;727;9682;2756;9711;1246;9941;6639;4899;7897;3967;1706;597;805;634;5214;5166;4032;9771;2281;4128;1494;6241;909;1925;1674;7730;5786;6453;7312;6413;8724;2384;7467;5749;5915;1788;7441;3580;8413;8679;1724;7779;3123;372;8389;4212;7340;4884;9735;3675;1677;8640;2398;2077;6149;2061;1441;6251;2116;7051;6422;4875;3534;6657;2710;8129;4193;5621;5144;6478;6122;3874;5501;1199;3607;6984;3406;6264;2828;9484;8087;8813;7047;5932;599;8560;3145;5939;8353;7783;9131;9607;7985;8072;9231;3532;258;3536;2469;1528;4649;3682;8661;3938;8350;3397;8006;4363;9612;9503;340;8481;6577;269;8950;5921;2505;2463;3668;1581;8341;3828;8297;8764;2788;6040;9317;1508;7452;3964;8988;5213;4270;2961;6543;8482;7303;7062;7378;4747;6725;6965;7798;9873;6224;6760;591;9965;6056;9641;1040;8548;1061;28;7473;6952;9145;9879;3166;1887;5657;4883;5984;7322;9930;103;6038;4865;7649;1206;1399;7649;6944;9656;8176;7616;3710;3445;6728;26;7739;8025;3268;2506;4921;5215;8393;9246;6213;1977;5685;4172;8541;8272;4990;2691;2272;1816;7734;3156;1303;3425;57;1411;5643;7063;9703;5439;3016;3343;6045;1759;6772;6940;3058;382;4342;6238;2320;7052;3241;1490;6935;1552;932;3439;8766;1404;3383;202;6721;2086;9698;5731;655;6815;5720;4062;9316;5136;820;1534;4090;5568;1173;6578;5460;176;3922;9855;7028;4929;8123;1705;697;6340;6079;3200;4465;5919;6381;6169;3350;9608;5343;6951;1830;3838;5858;7820;3266;656;1118;2823;7404;1867;145;2606;247;5220;8994;8260;11;4340;7238;9754;2070;396;4833;4811;7516;7210;3682;1152;572;1422;4699;2839;961;9022;879;2698;6956;6901;4688;3209;3050;978;1505;1392;2607;1796;4321;2745;9482;8930;4234;6066;2939;5845;9554;4440;6000;2309;3481;8585;1869;2936;2100;1475;5326;6009;1455;9108;9118;3756;9823;1602;775;6367;6544;8497;7940;376;4050;3835;5603;6260;2984;7279;8152;2676;8659;9670;9307;889;4586;9443;4187;7113;5818;4174;1120;373;4761;232;7038;7327;1275;826;5902;4909;3775;6336;5799;1605;3265;9933;7414;2266;1771;3860;9461;5205;9855;5482;4396;10;3809;7575;4090;9657;2716;568;1510;2945;5482;8908;6774;471;6401;9368;831;6529;785;439;8296;4540;796;3725;7204;1438;8769;4977;3829;2739;3853;6767;8379;7001;3594;3147;1468;1090;704;7456;7105;3673;4269;7843;4422;6312;9451;5387;525;8975;4062;8754;4717;993;4359;2007;8129;8166;9079;6314;1885;368;9336;5420;2114;6333;1785;1061;6699;491;1339;9970;7308;6675;1603;7454;8100;2622;7570;843;4090;852;7158;3413;5114;3655;1070;1084;2423;1503;5826;303;8613;820;1002;342;3322;556;9407;3898;8265;8437;199;5212;5043;6935;1192;2860;6863;6525;1693;9516;8541;3259;6431;5294;3713;6518;5948;4531;9640;795;9239;6260;4081;3988;5745;697;7033;197;7328;8896;1514;4168;794;1828;2846;9104;4185;3332;7621;8783;8781;8302;5240;7946;7497;7264;1334;3869;383;3123;758;3866;9239;2259;4303;5549;2151;3335;2000;5969;5489;8590;7913;3217;2623;4973;3591;7788;3683;2422;2698;6902;7974;2660;1835;2696;5933;648;1538;2508;3454;6827;3221;1348;8340;4492;1525;5738;4893;1315;9435;7270;3272;8015;5527;6986;760;9235;3287;8045;5943;6370;3104;1599;7357;1153;422;9381;5045;772;7580;954;4621;8980;8521;7520;7285;3615;7667;1924;824;5092;7540;3236;6784;1529;4880;5741;4818;704;5901;3703;8621;422;4282;4549;9718;4995;324;8770;64;9623;4283;5201;6087;8886;5069;1648;7727;471;8320;3594;9033;1129;4503;5218;4864;4116;2697;4884;5401;1821;6410;1631;5031;5736;4189;8856;8090;8912;5826;339;3099;7812;7290;6094;1709;3180;9580;4548;7378;299;9340;9285;4671;1109;7316;5800;7962;9496;7171;2369;1031;7654;5150;4248;4296;6189;6644;5344;3450;4345;668;530;3346;6890;9794;5138;8323;9650;3147;29;3652;2939;4195;37;5930;733;5540;5382;6244;6414;2079;3232;2804;7380;6867;2029;435;6411;2830;4334;7914;9514;813;718;6782;8276;2317;2789;3765;7934;5358;3211;9235;4012;6526;2024;2400;9629;3939;8815;8403;8374;2774;190;4060;6000;2513;7710;1496;8121;8192;916;584;371;6636;6029;9989;2115;8524;6747;5520;2563;6543;6793;9073;2092;8122;3207;2705;4323;2769;5490;4224;3627;9728;3692;8786;596;836;7253;381;1169;8958;2399;969;7885;3807;2852;4541;4114;307;6224;5514;2974;4709;4353;6265;4404;9730;8995;2704;5877;1989;1431;2294;3929";

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int> ParseManually()
        {

            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            List<string> subStr = new List<string>();

            int pos = inputData.IndexOf(";");
            int i = 0;
            int prevPos = pos;

            while (pos > -1)
            {
                string tempStr = "";
                if (i == 0)//Start
                {
                    tempStr = inputData.Substring(0, pos);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempStr = inputData.Substring(prevPos + 1, (pos - prevPos - 1));
                }

                subStr.Add(tempStr);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    prevPos = pos;
                }
                pos = inputData.IndexOf(";", pos + 1);
                i++;
                if (pos == -1)//Last Value
                {
                    tempStr = inputData.Substring(prevPos + 1);
                    subStr.Add(tempStr);
                }
            }
            //Coverting string values to int
            foreach (string str in subStr)
            {
                numbers.Add(Int16.Parse(str));
            }

            return numbers;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int> ParseWithLinq()
        {
            return inputData.Split(';').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<ParseDelimitedStringToListOfInts>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran the benchmark:

```
dotnet run -c Release
```

The results are interesting:

```
|        Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev |
|-------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|
| ParseManually | 613.0 us | 7.42 us | 6.58 us |
| ParseWithLinq | 212.6 us | 3.56 us | 4.24 us |
```

The result surprised me! It turns out that not only is this code much shorter, it is almost **3x faster**:

```
return inputData.Split(';').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and the [Benchmark] really makes things more interesting as i wanted to know how fast my manual code will perform.

Comment: @JuniorJ No problem! Both your manual code and the shorter `Split()` version run in milliseconds (or less) even for thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much easier:

```
string receivedIDs = "1020;8922;333;14;58;446;70;98";
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
string[] idFromString = receivedIDs.Split(';');
foreach(string s in idFromString)
{
   numbers.Add(int.Parse(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string receivedIDs = "1020;8922;333;14;58;446;70;98";
var numbers = receivedIDs.Split(';').Select(id => Int16.Parse(id)).ToList();
```